# Model is performing good on test set, but bad at train and validation set

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, confusion-matrix

i build up a CNN using Mobile net in a transfer learning approach where i just retrained the bottom 20 layers. i made a Train, validation and test set.

During training i could see both my test and validation loss reach almost zero, also my accuracy where above 95% n this train & validation set.

If after this training i ran the model on my test set, which the model hasn't seen, i could see that i had 99% accuracy on my test set. but if i did the prediciton on my training or validation set i saw that the results where around 50%, where during training the model scored about 95% on these?

What could be the reson behind this? is this normal behaviour? i was expecting the same results on training and validation set...

Some insight, i generated the set usin gthe imageDataGenerator.

```
IMAGE_SIZE = (250,750)

src_path_train = "Data/Train/"
src_path_test = "Data/Test/"

class_labels = [x for x in os.listdir(src_path_train) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(src_path_train,x)) and x[0]!='.']
print('Class labels : ', class_labels)

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range = 5, #nw 3
        width_shift_range = 0.01, #nw 0.001
        height_shift_range = 0.01, #nw
        rescale = 1./255,
        shear_range = 0.005,
        zoom_range = 0.005, #nw 0.001
        brightness_range = [0.8, 1.2], #nw 10%
        fill_mode = 'nearest',
        validation_split = 0.2)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1 / 255.0)


training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(str(src_path_train), target_size=IMAGE_SIZE, class_mode='categorical', subset='training', interpolation="lanczos", batch_size=25, shuffle=True)
validation_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(str(src_path_train), target_size=IMAGE_SIZE, class_mode='categorical', subset='validation', interpolation="lanczos", batch_size=25, shuffle=True)

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(str(src_path_test), target_size=IMAGE_SIZE, interpolation="lanczos", batch_size=54, shuffle=False)
```

After this i import mobile net and set the last 20 layers to trainable:

```
base_model=MobileNet(weights='imagenet',include_top=False, input_shape=(250, 750, 3)) #imports the mobilenet model and discards the last 1000 neuron layer.

x=base_model.output
x=GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x=Dense(1024,activation='relu')(x) #we add dense layers so that the model can learn more complex functions and classify for better results.
x=Dropout(0.2)(x)
# x=Dense(1024,activation='relu')(x) #dense layer 2
x=Dense(128,activation='relu')(x) #dense layer 3
x=Dropout(0.2)(x)
x=Dense(64,activation='relu')(x) #dense layer 3
x=Dropout(0.2)(x)
preds=Dense(2,activation='softmax')(x) #final layer with softmax activation

model=Model(inputs=base_model.input,outputs=preds)



for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable=False #False
# or if we want to set the first 20 layers of the network to be non-trainable
for layer in model.layers[:20]:
    layer.trainable=False
for layer in model.layers[20:]:
    layer.trainable=True
```

I do the training using fit

```
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=10)
mc = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.h5', monitor='val_loss', mode='min', save_best_only=True, verbose=1)

class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight(
               'balanced',
                np.unique(training_set.classes), 
                training_set.classes)
class_weights = dict(enumerate(class_weights))            
print('Class weights : ', class_weights)

steps_per_epoch = int(np.ceil(training_set.samples / training_set.batch_size))
print('Training steps per epoch: ', steps_per_epoch)

Valsteps_per_epoch = int(np.floor(validation_set.samples / validation_set.batch_size))
print('Validation steps per epoch: ', Valsteps_per_epoch)


history = model.fit(training_set, 
                            epochs=100,
                            class_weight = class_weights,
                            # steps_per_epoch= 30, #steps_per_epoch,
                            validation_data=validation_set,
                            # validation_steps= 10, #Valsteps_per_epoch,
                            verbose=1,
                            callbacks=[es, mc])
```

Then i start my predicitons using this piece of code:

```
set = test_set #training_set # validation_set

y_predicted = model.predict(set) # sequential model = predict_classes
```

I then achieve the confusion matrices as shown underneath, see how good it scores on the test set, and how bad is is performing on the train set.

Results on test set:

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      0.96      0.98        26
           1       0.97      1.00      0.98        28

    accuracy                           0.98        54
   macro avg       0.98      0.98      0.98        54
weighted avg       0.98      0.98      0.98        54

(array([[25,  1],
       [ 0, 28]], dtype=int64),)
98.14814814814815
```

Results on train set:

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.48      0.48      0.48        85
           1       0.54      0.54      0.54        96

    accuracy                           0.51       181
   macro avg       0.51      0.51      0.51       181
weighted avg       0.51      0.51      0.51       181

(array([[41, 44],
       [44, 52]], dtype=int64),)
51.38121546961326
```

What is responsbile for these results? could someone shed his light on this?
Thx!

--- Confusion matrix generation:

```
set = test_set #training_set # validation_set

y_predicted = model.predict(set) # sequential model = predict_classes

# print('1. ', y_predicted)
y_predicted = np.argmax(y_predicted,axis=1)
print('2. ', y_predicted)

y_test = set.labels
# y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(set.labels)
# print(y_test)
print(set.labels)

print(classification_report(y_test, y_predicted)),

cf = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_predicted),

print(cf),
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_predicted) * 100)
```

Comment: It might be because you set `training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(..., shuffle=True)`. Try without shuffling.

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the case, i am still fideling my way around those imageDataGernerators...

Comment: Can you show your code that generates the `confusion matrices` using `y_predicted`

Comment: It's at the bottom of my initial post, is there a way to capture the correct labels comming rom the generator in the sequnece that it's being fed into the predict method?